# working of where condition in sas proc sql, while connecting to some other database

Tags: sql, sas, sybase

I am working on a table with more that 30 million records.The table is on sybase and i am working on sas. There is a feed_key(numeric) variable which contains the time stamp for the record entry. I wanted to pull records for a particular time frame.

```
proc sql ;
Connect To Sybase (user="id" pass="password" server=concho);
create table table1 as
select * from connection to sybase
(
select a.feed_key as feed_key,
              a.cm15,
              a.country_cd,
              a.se10,
              convert(char(10),a.se10) as se_num,
              a.trans_dt,
              a.appr_deny_cd,
              a.approval_cd,
              a.amount        
         from abc.xyz a
  where a.country_cd in ('ABC') and a.appr_deny_cd in ('0','1','6') and a.approval_cd not in ('123456') and feed_key > 12862298
);
disconnect from sybase;
quit;
```

it is pulling same no of records, irrespective of whether i put the feed_key condition or not, and it is taking almost same time to execute(16 mins without feek_key condition and 15 mins with feed_key condition) the query.

please clarify the working of where clause in this case.

as i believe the feed_key condition should have made the query run much faster as more than 80% of records do not match this condition....

Comment: If you are certain that the passthrough succeeded, you better tag it as sybase. If you're not certain, it is the first thing to find out. If you are certain it did not use the passthrough, please mention it explicitly.

Comment: The code uses explicit passthrough and there's nothing SAS specific regarding number of rows returned. Simply verify your assumptions about data. Try running count(*) query in some SQL client. If feed_key is most restrictive part of WHERE clause, make sure it's indexed in database.

Comment: the table is not indexed on feed_key.
Question is: why is it taking almost same time to execute even after I put a where condition?

Comment: Try putting the feed_key condition first in the where clause, order does matter. (i.e. `where feed_key > 12862298 and a.country_cd in ('ABC') and a.appr_deny_cd in ('0','1','6') and a.approval_cd not in ('123456')`)

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting the same number of records back, it'll take the same amount of time to process the query.

This is because the I/O (transferring data back to SAS and storing it) is the most time-consuming part of the operation. This is why the lack of index doesn't make a big impact on the total time.

If you adjust your query so that it returns fewer rows, you will get faster processing.

You can tell whenever this is the case by looking at the SAS log, which will show you how much time was used by the CPU (the rest is IO):

```
    NOTE: PROCEDURE SQL used (Total process time):
          real time           11.07 seconds
          cpu time            1.67 seconds
```